# How to make view align at the bottom

Tags: android

Supposed that I have the following screen layout:
[image]

I have an `AdView` at the bottom of the page. I also have a floating button just above it. The whole layout is in `RelativeLayout`. When I set the `AdView` to `GONE`, the floating button is nowhere to be found. I set the layout parameters of the floating button to be above the `AdView` and is `alignParentRight`. What is the best thing to do to make sure that the floating button remains in the right bottom corner of the screen even after setting the visibility of `AdView` to `GONE`?

If I put the two views inside a `LinearLayout`, the result will be this one:
[image]

Here's the XML code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/cpnt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/alkitabfeedback_step_pager_selected_tab_color"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab_play_audio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignParentRight="false"

            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_audio"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:visibility="visible"
            ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You'd use a CoordinatorLayout here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should put your `AdView` and `FloatActionButton` into the `LinearLayout`(set **orientation=vertical**). The `FloatActionButton` is on the right of the `LinearLayout` and the `AdView` has **width="match_parent"**. The `LinearLayout` will be put at the bottom of the screen like you was done with the `AdView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#00ff00"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Or using `ConstraintLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="#00ff00"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: I have updated my problem. I am still having problem in LinearLayout

Comment: Could you show me your `LinearLayout` which contains `FloatActionButton` and `AdView` ?

Comment: I have put your `LinearLayout` into a `RelativeLayout`. When I set `android:visibility="gone"` to `AdView` directly in the layout editer I saw that the `AdView` was not visible any more and the `FloatActionButton` moved down to the bottom. Could you check it ?

Answer (score 1):

use Linear layout and android:gravity="bottom" to set this lay out

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#00ff00"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the visibility to `GONE`, you could try to adjust its height to 0.

`adview.getLayoutParams().height = 0;`

Comment: Or set the visibility to INVISIBLE

Comment: If I set it to invisible, there will be a white space at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Set the buttons params to:

```
alignParentRight=true
layout_above="+id/adView"
```